# Как вставить два работающих счётчика отсчёта времени?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. На сайте mn27.ru понадобилось вставить два счётчика отсчёта времени. Счётчик времени на ЯваСкрипт Пока стоит один, всё работает. Вставляю другой, второй не работает (его вообще не отображает). Если создаю для второго счётчика другой яваскрипт файл, и меняю ID для дива второго счётчика, то он начинает работать, а на первом время замирает.
Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Может хоть намекнете, что это за счетчик? Какой плагин используете?

Comment: Я же дал ссылку. Там в коде можно посмотреть. Сайт простой на HTML. 
Код для вставки счётчика:
<DIV ID="countdown"></DIV>
<SCRIPT src="http://mn27.ru/scripts/countdown.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></SCRIPT>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Скрипт очень не предназначен для параллельной работы... Он юзает одни и те же переменные, если вы создадите из даже 10.

Проще всего будет сделать второй такой же файл... И во-втором заменить все countdownid на countdownid2 и CountDowndmn2...

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую. Наверное это то, что нужно для сайта, состоящего из нескольких HTML-страничек.

Comment: Костыль же.

Comment: @KaZaца Да, но делается за 1 минуту и работает. 

Вам же никто не запрещает переписать это всё с нуля с поддержкой многоэкземплярности, ну и в целом можно как-то по-аккуратнее сделать. Смысл?

Answer (score 0):

Меняем

```
function CountDowndmn(yr,m,d,countdownid) //передаем в функцию собственный элемент

setTimeout(function(){CountDowndmn(yr,m,d,countdownid)},1000); //меняем таймер

CountDowndmn(2012,12,31,document.getElementById("countdown"));//вызываем 
CountDowndmn(2012,12,31,document.getElementById("another_countdown"));
```

Comment: С такими исправлениями счётчик вообще перестал работать

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kazatca/63zNX/ 
Подарок на новый год.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/YJAFC/)

Всё работает

Answer (score 0):

рекомендую в подобных ситуациях прибегать к анонимным функциям которые позволяют разделять пространство имен

```
(function(){
//тут пишем код
//все что тут будет автоматически запущено при запуске сайта
var s=1;
})();

(function(){
//тут пишем код
//все что тут будет автоматически запущено при запуске сайта
var s=2;//мы не перезаписываем старую s. т.к. она в другом пространстве имен!!!
})();
```

получить значение **s** тут не получится